# Missing fields when importing shapefile to PostgreSQL/PostGIS using Geotools

Tags: postgis, shapefile, geotools

I want to import shapefiles to database using geotools , the code below worked for only one shapefile ( which was imported successfully ) , so I supposed my code was working fine , but when I ve tried importing other shapefiles that I have , all the fields were missing in the database table except 'the_geom' field. Im unable to find the problem with my code . I only think that it's because I'm only using the '.shp' file so the code can't read information from '.dbf' file ? . Normally the first method that I've coded takes the path of the shapefile as argument so automatically it can read the other information from the other files ' .dbf ' , ' .shx ' . but since I have to link this with my frontEnd, there is no way to retrieve the path so I have to sent the whole file.
if my guess is right , how can I retrieve information from the dbf file and have a successful import of the shapefile ?

my code :

```
   public test (File  shapefile, String b) throws  NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
  
    
    String postGISTblName = b;//name to give to the newly created table 
    String shapeEPSG = "EPSG:4326";//the epsg to use if not found from shpefile
        try {
        
           FileDataStore shapeDataStore = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(shapefile);
       
                     // feature type
           String typeName = shapeDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
           FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType,SimpleFeature> featSource = shapeDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
           FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType,SimpleFeature> featSrcCollection=featSource.getFeatures();
           SimpleFeatureType ft = shapeDataStore.getSchema(typeName);

          

 // feature type copy to set the new name
           SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
           builder.setName(postGISTblName);
           builder.setAttributes(ft.getAttributeDescriptors());
           builder.setCRS(ft.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());

           SimpleFeatureType newSchema = builder.buildFeatureType();

          
           
           
        

       
               CoordinateReferenceSystem crsEpsg = CRS.decode(shapeEPSG);
                newSchema = SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder.retype(newSchema,crsEpsg);
            

            
            
            Map postGISParams = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            postGISParams.put("dbtype", "postgis");         //must be postgis
            postGISParams.put("host", "localhost");         //the name or ip address of the machine running PostGIS
            postGISParams.put("port",5433);                 //the port that PostGIS is running on (generally 5432)
            postGISParams.put("database", "DB");       //the name of the database to connect to.
            postGISParams.put("user", "postgres");          //the user to connect with
            postGISParams.put("passwd", "passw");    //the password of the user.
            postGISParams.put("schema", "public");        //the schema of the database
            postGISParams.put("create spatial index", Boolean.TRUE);
            DataStore dataStore = null;
            try {
            // storage in PostGIS
            dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(postGISParams);
            } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("problem with datastore:"+e);
            }
           
            if (dataStore == null) {
             System.out.println("ERROR:dataStore is null");
            } 
            
            dataStore.createSchema(newSchema);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            FeatureStore<SimpleFeatureType,SimpleFeature> featStore = (FeatureStore<SimpleFeatureType,SimpleFeature>)dataStore.getFeatureSource(postGISTblName);
        
            featStore.addFeatures(featSrcCollection);

      //      System.out.println(a);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:"+e);
        }
       
     //  System.out.println("Shapefile imported successfully !!!!!");

}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what files are in the folder with the `.shp` file with the same basename as it?

Comment: @IanTurton they all have the mandatory files '.shp',  ' .dbf ' and '.shx' + the optional ones like '.prj' , '.sbn ' , '.sbx'

Comment: what do you mean by "but since I have to link this with my frontEnd, there is no way to retrieve the path so I have to sent the whole file."?

Comment: @IanTurton what I meant by that : before I link my banckEnd to my frontEnd , I had a Java method that takes the path of the shapefile as argument and the import works fine  [link](http://freeopengis.blogspot.com/2016/02/importing-esri-shapefiles-into-dbs.html) .  but since there is no way to get the full path of a selected file by the user ,  I changed the code which is the code above , the method now takes the file as argument. and when the user select a shapefile , I sent it via Ajax for the import.

Comment: so are you sending all the files or just the `.shp` - I think you need to send a zip file and unpack it on the server

Comment: @IanTurton  that's my question , if I send all the files , how the code will read the information from the other files like '.dbf ' ?  when we work with the path , the informations from the other files are read automatically , I couldn't find how to read information from the other files so that the import works correctly

Comment: Because that is how it works, it finds the shp and then looks for the others

Comment: @IanTurton but that's not what happens when I work with the files ( as argument) instead of the path ( as argument ) . In my postgis table , I only find 'the_geom' field , the other fields are missing , which means it couldn't read informations from the other files.

Comment: please edit your question with the **exact** details of which files are in the folder your program is trying to read, the name of the file and folder when it works and when it doesn't